# VBScript RegEx group match with back reference issue

Tags: regex, vbscript, web-config

I have a line in my web.config which is as follows

```
<clientDependency loggerType="xxx.ClientDependencies.Logger,StrattonWebShared" version="144">
```

What I am trying to do is write a script which checks my code base for modifications and then updates the clientDependency module version by 1 if any found. So the code bit to increase the version by one is as follows

```
Set clientDepRegExp = new RegExp
    clientDepRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
    clientDepRegExp.Global = True
    clientDepRegExp.Pattern = "(<clientDependency.*version=\"")(\d+)(\"".*)"

    '1 = open file for reading
    Set clientDependencyConfigFile = fileSystemObject.OpenTextFile(targetFile, 1)

    fileContents = clientDependencyConfigFile.ReadAll

    clientDependencyConfigFile.Close

    fileContents = clientDepRegExp.Replace(fileContents, "$1" & CInt("$2") + 1 & "$3")
```

My problem is with the last line. `$2` is the version number and doing `CInt("$2") + 1` is just giving me `3` (so `2 + 1` that is). If I just use `"$2"` then its returning `144` (refer to the first line for version number). SO my question is if I wana do a quick arithmatic inside replace how should I do it?

Thanks in advance for any tips ans suggestions that you can provide

Comment: Would be great if I could get an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change your code something like that:**

```
Set clientDepRegExp = New RegExp
Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
With clientDepRegExp
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "(<clientDependency[^<>]*?version="")(\d+)\b"
    fileContents = fso.OpenTextFile(targetFile).ReadAll
    tmp = .Replace(reftext, "$2")
    fileContents = .Replace(reftext, "$1" & CStr(Val(tmp) + 1))
End With
```

---

Hope this work.